# React context only passes down one value

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-context

I have been working on a React Native project and have come across a strange bug in my code where useContext will only read one of the passed-down values from my provider.

My provider is here:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export default function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

My entire app project is here

```
import React from "react";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import SettingsProvider from "./src/SettingsProvider";
import TheatersProvider from "./src/TheatersProvider";
import UserProvider from "./src/UserProvider";
import PurchaseProvider from "./src/PurchaseProvider";
import LoginDisplay from "./src/Login/LoginDisplay";
import Main from "./src/Main/Main";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <UserProvider>
        <SettingsProvider>
          <TheatersProvider>
            <PurchaseProvider>
              <Stack.Navigator
                initialRouteName="LoginDisplay"
                screenOptions={{
                  headerShown: false,
                }}
              >
                <Stack.Screen name="LoginDisplay" component={LoginDisplay} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </PurchaseProvider>
          </TheatersProvider>
        </SettingsProvider>
      </UserProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And the component which has been dealing with issues is here

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { SettingsContext } from "../../SettingsProvider";
import { UserContext } from "../../UserProvider";

export default function EditProfile({
  visible,
  setVisible,
  update,
  profilePic,
}) {
  const { settings } = useContext(SettingsContext);
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

For some reason, the component is able to read the value of the user but returns undefined when trying to access setUser. I don't know why this is happening, especially because I have been able to access setUser in a different part of my application without issues.

Comment: Why don't you pass the default value in creating the context ? 

```export const UserContext = createContext(DefaultContextValue);```

Comment: Can you provide a snack to reproduce the issue?